# Change the checkbox mark color in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

My app uses gray background, i change the border of checkbox with borderbrush, but i dont find any attribute to change the color of the mark within checkbox. So, any solution ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options. If we go check out the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709910.aspx) the glyph `Path` that makes the checkmark visual has a `Fill` assigned to `CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush` which you could change at the template level. Or at the resource level where you would find that resource declaration. Or you could change it at the instance level.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: your example doesnt work, so i think i should try another solution. thanks ^^

Comment: @user3448806 no matter how you slice it you're still going to have to change the Fill color on the shape that is the checkmark. Not sure if that template applies to phone or not now that you mention it. Just go look at the default template for your checkmark and change it there....that is the solution, no other way around it amigo, even if my names are wrong something you'll still have to interact with that shape..

Comment: @user3448806 Chris is correct. This is the way to do this. It's either you adjust the default template or you roll your own checkbox (which honestly wouldn't be that difficult. Just a image control, a border and a PNG of a checkbox with what ever color you want) but if you are having trouble with the template I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on the Resources property of the control:

```
DirectCast(Checkbox1.Resources("CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush"),  
    SolidColorBrush).Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. Checkbox1.Resources("CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush") returns Nothing. I do tried with checkbox named "Checkbox1" :)